# MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7 failing to install

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to install MySQL for visual studio 1.2.7 into my windows 7 computer to use with my visual studio 2017 pro but it is progressing till 80% then performing a rollback and failing entirely. I have tried using a stand alone installer and also installing it using MySQL installer but the same thing happens.
I would like assistance on how I can have it successfully installed or if there is an alternative for it.

HERE is a link to the extracted log file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dhsdzc9xqBqMtgr2IJ8eGztM-LQUK4V2/view?usp=sharing

Note: I have visual studio installed on disk C and so is MySQL
Thanks

Comment: Look at event viewer to find the exact cause of the error. Without an error message none can help you.

Comment: here is the log file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dhsdzc9xqBqMtgr2IJ8eGztM-LQUK4V2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i have same issue. Created a proj from VS2013 installed mysql plugin 1.1, can update but once I transferred to VS2017, and installed mysql plugin 1.2, it won't update edmx.